# The set of unit-preserving ($u + x = u'$) elements $x$ of a $\Bbb{Z}/n$ form an ideal. Can we compute what it's isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $U$ be any subset of the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n$.  Then the set of all $x \in \Bbb{Z}/n$ such that $U + x \subset U$ forms an ideal $I_U$ of $\Bbb{Z}/n$.

Now let $U$ be the set of units modulo $n$.  Is there a formula that describes $I_U$ in terms of the divisors of $n$?

$$
\Bbb{Z}/9: \\
U = \{1,2,4,5,7,8\} \\
I_U = \{0,3,6\} \simeq \Bbb{Z}/3
$$

Is it just equal to the nilradical?  I know that it seems to vanish for $\operatorname{rad}(n) = n$, which is exactly what the nilradical does modulo $n$.  In that case it would be isomorphic to $\operatorname{rad}(n)\Bbb{Z}/n$.  Or does it properly contain the nilradical sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $n=p^{k}$, the answer for $I_{U}$ is $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
For $x\in I_{U}$, it must lie in $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and conversely for any $x$ in this ideal and $u\in U$, we have:
$$(u+x)=u(1+u^{-1}x)=[u^{-1}(1-u^{-1}x+u^{-2}x^{2}-\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}u^{-(k-1)}x^{k-1})]^{-1}\in U.$$
For the general case, if $n=p_{1}^{k_{1}}\cdots p_{m}^{k_{m}}$, by Chinese remainder theorem we can see $I_{U}=p_{1}\cdots p_{m}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.